# Rspec: How to access current seed number on failed example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, continuous-integration

To identify flaky specs we log them in a table with a counter. So everytime a spec fails on our CI, we either update the count of an existing record in the table or write a new record. On a regular basis we dedicate some time to fix the specs with the highest count.

It would be very helpful to also log the seed of the current test run. Is there a way to access this from the exception?

What we use right now to log the exception is the `ExceptionPresenter`:

```
RSpec::Core::Formatters::ExceptionPresenter.new(example.exception, example)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this one will help you ([Rubydoc](https://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration#seed-instance_method)):

```
RSpec.configuration.seed
```